# Download link of Sinch Android SDK zip not available

Tags: java, sinch, android-sinch-api

I want to integrate a video and audio chating feature to my app, so I choose sicnh https://developers.sinch.com/page/downloads

But I can't download the Android SDK zip https://download.sinch.com/android/3.15.0/sinch-android-rtc-3.15.0.zip

When I click on it, i see in my browser:

```
403 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.

The Amazon CloudFront distribution is configured to block access from your country. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.

Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: d7fKvF74JU_NtzGa5Ljan0aOxxo1oRwc9vPQc5-w89RwI0Fchp_i6A==
```

How To dowload the Android SDK zip ?

I'm now located at Guinea(west africa).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sinch SDK is not available to download for some countries. This is caused by Sinch needing to remain compliant with the relevant regulations and laws for offering this kind of technology.